# Attachment base64 in emailjs

Tags: javascript, image, email, gmail, base64

I use [emailjs](https://github.com/eleith/emailjs) for sending email.
I have base64 string.
When i send html body with

```
attachment:
[
   {data:"<html> <body> <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAFA3PEY8..."> </body> </html>", alternative:true}
]
```

Not all e-mail clients display the `<img src="base64">` (eg gmail web or Outlook)

I want to attach a file from base64. How can I do it?

I tried so but the picture comes damaged:

```
attachment:
[
  {data:"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAFA3PEY8...", encoded:true, name:"file.jpeg",type:"image/jpeg"},
]
```

PS: my server settings:

```
"host" : "smtp.gmail.com",
"user" : "***@gmail.com",
"password" : "******",
"ssl" : true,
"port" : 465
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the base64 string without the format data (I had the same problem but managed to fix it this way):

```
attachment:
[
   {data:"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAFA3PEY8...", encoded:true, name:"file.jpeg",type:"image/jpeg"},
]
```

In other words, get the data string without anything else. You could use something like this to match it:

```
var data = yourBase64DataUrl.match(/base64,(.+)$/);
var base64String = matches[1];

...

attachment: [
    {data: base64String, encoded:true, name:"file.jpeg",type:"image/jpeg"},
]
```